# No Article Problem: A Person’s Title?

Tags: articles, zero-article

I wonder how to explain this regular zero article in such constructions:

1. Ray Bradbury, author of *Fahrentheit 451*.
2. Karl Marx, creator of Marxism.

I can see that the second example may be explained as a title or something like this. But what is the first one?

Comment: Where did you see the phrases?

Comment: @Astralbee As a regular (ie non-mod) user, the system doesn’t let me close as duplicates of “unanswered” questions. In this case, I was able to cast a duplicate because the answer there has been designated by the community as a good answer, through upvotes. The answer to both questions is the same.

Comment: @laurel Not sure how it works, but if this one gets an accepted answer then maybe the other should be closed as a duplicate? I just looked at your link and it doesn't really cover the 2 different reasons distinctly enough for my liking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to start with a quote from the movie *Gladiator*:

> My name is Maximus Decimus Meridius, commander of the Armies of the North, General of the Felix Legions, loyal servant to the true emperor, Marcus Aurelius. Father to a murdered son, husband to a murdered wife.

As you can see, he is a commander, a general, a father and a husband, but none of these requires an article.

When a description of a job role is *unique*, or when you have already *named one specific person* who holds that role, you can optionally omit the article.

**Examples:**

- He is *an* author.

This requires the indefinite article because there are many authors.

- He is *the* author of *Farenheit 451*.

Because there is only one author of that specific title, the definite article can be used, or it can be omitted:

- He is author of *Fareheith 451*.

You can also omit the article if the person is specifically *named*, for example:

- Ray Bradbury, author and screenwriter, died in 2012.

Comment: Thank you very much! I understand now.